# Scipy Optimizer or heuristic approach, which to choose for bottleneck capacity

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am not able to formulate the below problem into `scipy's` `linprog` or `minimize` due to complex constraint condition. So wanted to check if there are other modules that allow below format of block constraints.

[image: here]

Since, this also checks for the bottleneck capacity(which is taken care of by constraints in `B14`) my check was whether we should go for direct solvers or take a heuristic approach where we assign random numbers and keep re-balancing towards the slowest process. Iterating till numbers seem to converge ?.

Details of the problem :

`Objective` : F9, F10, F11 each individually and such that all are almost same(it's a constraint) - Background is that consider p1,p2 and p3 as serial processes and so I want maximum throughput from each and the same.(factoring bottleneck)

`Variables` : C6:E8. These are percentage allocation and hence should be between (0,1)(bound)

`Constraint` : i)Mentioned in 'objective' - the total output for each process should be the same.
i.e. F9 = F10 = F11.

ii)Also sum of allocation for a specific machine should be 100%. i.e. sum(C6:C8) = 1, sum(D6:D8) = 1 and sum(E6:E8) = 1

I need help in formulating the first constraint. How can I add a equation to ensure equality of those 3 cells(F9:F11) ?

Comment: Could you write it in a way that it becomes clear what i) your objective function is what ii) your constraints are and iii) which variables you have?

Comment: @Cleb improved the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### General advice

Please show some attempts and make sure your problem is well-defined! Without the former people are not that motivated as they assume you did not even try. The latter asks for solutions to a problem never asked for!

I'm assuming, your objective is to maximize `f9 + f10 + f11`.

#### Advice part 2

To be honest: in Linear-programming, this problem is quite simple and does not have *complex constraint conditions!* To tackle tasks like these, make sure to understand the [standard-form of LPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Standard_form) which is more or less everything you need to do here (and linprog's API is even easier to use than a *real* standard-form).

#### Code-intro

As mentioned: all we need to do is to model an LP for this. The basic idea here:

- introduce helper-variables which mimic your intermediate-values used in other constraints

  - a good solver with presolving capabilities will not be hurt by those introduced variables (which will easy the formulation)
  - scipy's linprog has two different solvers:

    - as far as i know: only the IPM-one has (advanced-) presolving
    - but for your model-size: no need for presolving: it's trivial!

**Remark:**

- i did not check the result

  - maybe i switched some 0/1; but the code will show you how to tackle the problem!
- i did not check the general idea of your optimization-problem (i assume it makes sense!)
- if this is a correct interpretation of your problem, you now also have your answer to: *what approach to take?* as LPs are very very fast to solve and a lot of free software is available

  - linprog faster & more robust (see remark at the end) than scipy's (more general nonlinear-based) minimize
  - optimal solution (if there is one) guaranteed to be found (in contrast to your alternative approach mentioned)

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

""" Create LP in (modified) standard-form for linprog-API """

# VARIABLES
# ---------
# vars: 9
# auxiliary/helper-vars: 12 -> c9, c10, c11, ..., f9, f10, f11
# all vars: 21
# layout x VECTOR: c6, c7, c8, d6, d7, d8, e6, e7, e8,
#  continued:      c9, c10, c11, d9, d10, d11, e9, e10, e11, f9, f10, f11

# BOUNDS
# ------
bounds = [(0, 1) for i in range(9)] + \
         [(None, None) for i in range(12)]  # aux-vars
            # depending on assumptions about input / model:
            # more restricted domains possible (e.g. nonnegative)!

# CONSTRAINTS
# -----------
# only equality constraints!

# example:
#     c3=2 * c6      = c9
# <->    2 * c6      = c9
# <->    2 * c6 - c9 = 0

# HANDMADE DENSE-MATRIX
# For more advanced tasks: scipy.sparse based constructions -> observe patterns!
A_eq = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],     # c6 + c7 + c8
                 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],     # d6 + d7 + d8
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],     # e6 + e7 + e8
                 [2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    # 2*c6 = c9
                 [0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    # ...
                 [0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    # ...
                 [0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    # 3*d6 = d9
                 [0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],    # ...
                 [0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0],    # ...
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0],    # 2*e6 = e9
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0],    # ...
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0],    # ...
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0],  # f9 = sum(c9, d9, e9)
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0],  # ...
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1],  # ...
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0],    # f9 = f10
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1]])   # f10 = f11

b_eq = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

# OBJECTIVE
# ---------
#     max  f9 + f10 + f11
# <-> min -f9 - f10 - f11
c = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1])

# SOLVE
# -----
res = linprog(c, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq, bounds=bounds)
print(res)

# GRAB SOL
x = res.x[:9].reshape((3,3), order='F')
print(x)
```

#### Output:

```
fun: -9.3333333333333339
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nit: 23
slack: array([ 0.77777778,  1.        ,  0.22222222,  0.77777778,  0.22222222,
   1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ])
status: 0
success: True
  x: array([ 0.22222222,  0.        ,  0.77777778,  0.22222222,  0.77777778,
   0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.44444444,
   0.        ,  3.11111111,  0.66666667,  3.11111111,  0.        ,
   2.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  3.11111111,  3.11111111,
   3.11111111])
[[ 0.22222222  0.22222222  1.        ]
[ 0.          0.77777778  0.        ]
[ 0.77777778  0.          0.        ]]
```

#### Advice part 3

Scipy's [linprog(method=’simplex’)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-simplex.html) looks very very buggy to me (see issues or other SO-questions)!

I highly recommend to use [linprog(method=’interior-point’)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-interior-point.html) if that's a possibility (make sure to understand the differences between Simplex and Interior-point methods!).

After some research, you will understand the output of method=IPM:

```
fun: -9.3333333333174284
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nit: 6
slack: array([], dtype=float64)
status: 0
success: True
  x: array([  2.22222222e-01,   2.31362354e-14,   7.77777778e-01,
    2.22222222e-01,   7.77777778e-01,   4.90542917e-13,
    1.00000000e+00,   3.30588524e-12,   1.94200136e-12,
    4.44444444e-01,  -3.21898064e-12,   3.11111111e+00,
    6.66666667e-01,   3.11111111e+00,  -4.57278659e-12,
    2.00000000e+00,   1.67288405e-12,   3.06199510e-13,
    3.11111111e+00,   3.11111111e+00,   3.11111111e+00])
```

#### Advice part 4

Special modelling-systems make those kind of formulations easier. So if you can afford to leave scipy and use external software (with more strict licenses), you can try Coin OR's pulp, Coin OR's pyomo, cvxpy and co. Those are very very different to each other with different use-cases.

Comment: I am very thankful for investing time to this. I remember your comments on another question related to this I had asked which helped e introduce to linprog. And I learnt how to solve it

Comment: However, for this case, this cannot be applied. It was my mistake because I didn't formulate my question well. Could you please look into the edited question. I will also look into the 'simplex' vs IPM definitely ! I have restrictions to use licensed solvers but can if this doesn't work

Comment: Please do not take the pain to solve with all syntax for me. I need are suggestions on how to formulate the constraints(if possible)

Comment: @joel.wilson It's not clear what you want. In the objective part you want F9, F10, F11 to be almost the same, while in the constraints they need to be the same. In the code above, they are constrained to be the same (so both are fulfilled)!  If it's wanted to maximize F9, F10, F11 each individually, and they are constrained to be the same, it's equivalent to maximime the sum (or just any component). Your edit does not introduce anything which is not part of the code already.

Comment: The solution is working great! I had 2 questions: is there any limit on the number of decision variables it can consider? and if incase equations like `0x+0y=0` exist, then would that be a problem ?

Comment: Theoretically no, practically yes (but we are talking about millions and those would need a fully automatic constraint-matrix generation in contrast to this demo). Solve-time is growing polynomially. Memory too. So there is no asymptotic problem (compared to NP-hard tasks). Additionally floating-point math will break things in some cases due to missing precisions. Hard to tell when this is going to work. IT highly depends on the values. ```0x+0y=0``` is not a problem until numerical-trouble occurs. Again... This one is hard to foresee (e.g. very small + very big values in data = bad)

Comment: Thanks! I am facing a challenge with one right now actually. I have 14 process and 11 machine. Thus 2*14*11+14 decision variables. However, its not giving me the right solution. Would you have a chance to look if I share one?

Comment: If it outputs status=optimal it is the right solution (in 99.999% of time; everything else are bugs) and the problem is your model, not the optimizer/code. The number of decision-vars in your comment is *tiny*!